# Differential equation and substitution.

Tags: definite-integrals

If the substitution square root of $x = \sin y$ is made in the $\int^0_{0.5}\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx$, what is the resulting integral?

Comment: Do you mean $$\int_{.5}^0\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}dx$$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams It's the same thing.

Comment: Are you sure the lower limit is $0.5$? (usually one uses the smaller number as lower limit, and if not, switch them and change sign)

Answer (score 1):

I will do $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, i.e., $\displaystyle \int_0^{0.5}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx$.

First, as $g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ is continuous in $(0,\frac{1}{2})$, it follows that this integral is not unfit.

Now, replace $1-x =u^2$, then $x=1-u^2$ and $dx=-2udu$.

Calculating the indefinite integral
$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1-x}}dx=-2\int \frac{\sqrt{1-u^2}\cdot u}{u}du =-2\int \sqrt{1-u^2} du =(*).$$

Now, do
$$\sin t=\sqrt{1-u^2}    \text{   and   } \cos t=u,$$
then $du=-\sin t dt$ and so
$$(*)=-2\int \sin t(-\sin t)dt=2\int \sin^2t dt=2\int \frac{1-\cos 2t}{2}dt= $$
$$=\int dt -\int \cos 2t dt=t-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2t+c=t-\sin t\cos t +c= $$
$$=\arccos u-u\sqrt{1-u^2}+c=\arccos\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1-x}\cdot\sqrt{x}+c. $$

Lastly,

$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}g(x)dx= \left.(\arccos\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1-x}\cdot\sqrt{x})\right|_0^{\frac{1}{2}}= $$
$$=\arccos \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}-\left( \arccos 1-0\right) =\frac{\pi-2}{4}.$$